# converting timestamp to relative time in android

Tags: android, timestamp, android-dateutils

`Timestamp` which I use is in the format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" now I want it to convert it into corresponding relative time . Have searched a lot on this topic . I know `DateUtils` can be used to do this , but I cannot find any method in `DateUtils` that uses `Timestamp` as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the `SimpleDateFormat` class:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html